# Stage of “Please wait...” takes a long time on Commit Window in Disk C with Tortoisegit

Tags: windows, performance, wait, tortoisegit

## 1 What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. clone repo in Disk C
2. right click, then Git Commit -> "develop"...
3. On Commit Window, Stage of “Please wait...” takes a long time(about 40 seconds).
   [image: t1]

## 2 What is the expected output? What do you see instead?

What expected: stage of “Please wait...” takes about 10 seconds.

What I see instead: stage of “Please wait...” takes about 40 seconds.

## 3 What version of TortoiseGit and Git are you using? On what operating system?

TortoiseGit 2.12.0.0 (D:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin)

Git version 2.33.0.windows.2 (d:\Program Files\Git\bin; d:\Program Files\Git\mingw64; d:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig)

Operating system: Windows 10, 2004, 19041.804

## 4 Please provide any additional information below.

### 4.1 Disk C Only

Stage of “Please wait...” takes a long time **only** in Disk C.

In Disk E,it take just about  10 seconds.

Repoes in Disk C and Disk E are the same.

And Disk C and Disk E are both SSD, results of speed test are as follows:

[image: t2]

### 4.2 Had reproduce it on other computers

I also test what I do above on other computers, all of them are the same:

Stage of “Please wait...” takes about 40 seconds **only** in Disk C, while takes about 10 seconds on the other Disk.

### 4.3 My Questions

So, what's so special about it Disk C?

What is Tortoisegit doing in Disk C?

Is it normal?

How can I speed up Stage of “Please wait...” in Disk C ?

As TortoiseGit is open source, showing me the code to explain questions above is the best.

Comment: Using [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) might give clues about what's happening differently

Answer (score 1):

TortoiseGit does not use "git status" (as of version 2.12), but uses different commands to compose the status (and also list the diff statuses, cf. https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/blob/master/src/Git/Git.cpp#L3255).

- git diff-index --cached --raw HEAD --numstat -C -M --
- git diff-index --raw HEAD --numstat -C -M --
- git ls-files -u -t
- git ls-files -d
- git ls-files --exclude-standard --full-name --others

If any of these command prints a file it will be listed in the commit dialog. Maybe one of these commands takes a longer time on C.

cross-ref: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/issues/3798